# What does arguments in following string object do?

Tags: java

```
public class PgHS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte ascii[] = {65,66,67,68,69,70};
        String s1 = new String(ascii,2,3);
        System.out.println(s1);
    }

}

// output: CDE
```

In this code, I thought the output would be `CD`, As array goes from `0` to `n`,the 2nd & 3rd position would be `67` and `68` which are the 
 ASCII equivalent of `CD`.

But the output was actually `CDE`. Why is this?

Comment: RTFM Daniel! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs:

```
String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length)
```

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified subarray of bytes using the platform's default charset.

In your case: It creates new string from your `ascii` input and starts at `ascii[2]` and length of string is `3` bytes long.

Your print should be `CDE`.